# Why doesn't the query return archived posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the "Archived post status" plugin to make posts archive. Here is the link of this plugin: [Archive post status](https://wordpress.org/plugins/archived-post-status/)

I’m trying to get archived posts between two dates: start date and end date, with wordpress query. The start date and end date comes from url, I'm taking them with $_GET. Here is my code:

```
$startDate = $_GET['startdate'];
$endDate = $_GET['enddate'];
$firstDayOfMonth = date(“Ym01”, strtotime($_GET[‘startdate’]));
$lastDayOfMonth = date(“Ymt”, strtotime($_GET[‘enddate’]));

$arguments = [
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'post_status' => 'archive',
  'post_type' => 'agenda',
  'meta_query' => [
       'relation' => 'AND',
       [
          'key' => 'date',
          'compare' => '>=',
          'value' => $firstDayOfMonth,
       ],
       [
          'key' => 'date',
          'compare' => '<=',
          'value' => $lastDayOfMonth,
       ]
   ] 
];
```

If I remove the meta query with start date and end date the query returns me archived posts, but with meta query, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Looks like you edited this code with a wordprocessor! These quotes `“` are not valid use `"` instead

Comment: Also what format are `$_GET['startdate'];` and `$_GET['endate'];` being passed to you in?

Comment: We need the date format that you receive by `$_GET` request to debug this code.

Comment: The date format that i received by $_GET is "Ymd" for example "20180509"

Comment: Also your single quotes `‘` should also be `'`

Comment: Read more here
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'state',
            'value' => 'Wisconsin',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'city',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ), 
    ),
) );
```

do like this i hope this work.
with array()

Ref :- [Link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/246355/order-by-multiple-meta-key-and-meta-value/246358#246358)

```
'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => '_my_custom_key_2',
            'value'   => 'Value I am looking for 2',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => '_my_custom_key_3',
            'value'   => 'Value I am looking for 3',
            'compare' => '='
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

First, You compare string values(meta_query understand `date` key like string), not numbers, so You need compare meta value like number(for better accuracy in format date seconds from 1970 for example (use `strtotime()`) if possible).

To say WordPress that the meta value must be compare like it is number, just add parameters `'type' => 'NUMERIC'` or `'type' => 'DECIMAL(10,3)'`(for float numbers) .

Example of arguments array for You:

```
$args = [
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'post_status' => 'archive',
  'post_type' => 'agenda',
  'meta_query' => [
       [
          'key' => 'date',
          'type' => 'DECIMAL(10,3)',
          'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
          'value' => array($firstDayOfMonth,$lastDayOfMonth)
       ]
   ] 
];
```

Also, before put array value `value` of start and end date to be sure recommend use `intval()` for date var.